# Django template main.html it's not seeing user logged

Tags: django, authentication, blogs

hi i have a problem with login function in django ,when i loggin succes see when user is logged but main.html didnot .

wiews

```
def user_login(request):
context = {}
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
    if user.is_authenticated:
        print("1")
        login(request, user)
        if request.GET.get('next',None):
            print("2")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET['next'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))
    else:
        print("3")
        context["error"] = "nieprawidlowe dane"
        return render(request,'auth/login.html',context)
else:
    print("4")
    return render(request,'auth/login.html',context)


 @login_required(login_url="/login/")
def success(request):
    c = {}
    c['user'] = request.user
    return render(request,'auth/success.html',c)
```

and in here is succes and on this page django can see when user is logged

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block article %}
<p>User <b>{{ user.username }}</b> jestes zalogowony</p>
<form method="post" action="/logout/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

but main.html didnot see user

Comment: In the view that renders `main.html`, add this line `print(request.user.is_authenticated)` to see actually whether the user is logged in

Comment: not any views render main.html directly all extends main.html but i write new function  `def test(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    render(request,'main.html')` and its true when it should be logged and false when should not

Comment: @M.B And how does your `main.html` look like? What variables do you check to test if user is logged in?

Comment: https://wklejaj.pl/16030    {% if user.is_authenticated %}